# check each row in column A against each row in column b in excel 2010

Tags: excel

I have two columns having different no of rows.The first column is a description and second column is keyword.
What I want is get each description from column 1 and check against each row in column 2 and in case matching print the column two value.
Example

```
desc                     keyword        expected result
asd asasc asd search     search          search
adasd ads adtasa         key2            dasd
adasf search asdsad      dasd            search
asdasd searchff                          dasd
asdasd searchff                          dasd
sadas key2sa sd                          key2
key2                                     key2
sads key2 sff                            key2
```

Comment: You're going to need to edit your question if anyone is to understand this...

Comment: you may need vba to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this formula:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6, ROW($B$2:$B$4)/(SEARCH($B$2:$B$4,A2)=AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH($B$2:$B$4,A2),1)),1))
```

[image]